# Include dependency

Tags: c++, oop, circular-dependency, forward-declaration

I have a PieceStrategy class:

```
#include "QueenStrategy.cpp"
class PieceStrategy {
    void promoteToQueen() {
        this = new QueenStrategy();
    }
}
```

And I have a QueenStrategy class which inherits from it:

```
#include "PieceStrategy.cpp"
class QueenStrategy : public PieceStrategy {}
```

Now arises the **circular includes problem.** But in this case, I cannot use forward declaration.

What should I do?

Comment: You shouldn't include cpp (implementation) files. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Doing `this = new ...` will not work as you expect it to. `*this = ...` might work partially, but it still won't make `this` an instance of the new class.

Comment: As for your problem, don't define the member function inline in the class, do it in a source file instead. Then you don't have to include the `"QueenStrategy.h"` header file in the `"PieceStrategy.h"` header file.

Comment: Oh wait, are you including *source files*? Don't to that! Use *header* files instead (with the `.h` ending), and separate source into *source* files (with `.cpp` ending).

Answer (score 4):

1. You should not include cpp files, but headers
2. You must not assign to `this`
3. Choose another design. You should not try to modify the strategy but select another one for the actual object, that uses that strategy.

piece.hpp

```
#include "strategy.hpp"
class Piece
{
    std::unique_ptr<Strategy> strategy;
public:
    static Piece Pawn();
    void PromoteToQueen();
};
```

piece.cpp

```
#include "pawn.hpp"
#include "queen.hpp"

Piece Piece::Pawn()
{
    Piece p;
    p.strategy = std::make_unique<PawnStrategy>();
    return p;
}

void Piece::PromoteToQueen()
{
    strategy = std::make_unique<QueenStrategy>();
}
```